# Is my argument wrong? (A combinatorial exercise)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How many ways are there to arrange $m$ distinct flags on a row of $r$ flagpoles? The order of the flags on the flagpoles (from top to bottom) matters.

My argument is: I have $mr$ points and I have to decide where to put the $m$ flags, so the result should be $\binom{mr}{m}$. But the second point of the exercise let me think that the right answer might be $m(m+1)\cdots(m+r-1)$ or $r(r+1)\cdots(r+m-1)$.

Is my argument wrong? And if it is, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is introduce the flags to the layout in a fixed order (say, alphabetical by the official French name of the country). For each flag, I have the option of *either* placing at the top of one of the $r$ flagpoles, *or* placing it immediately below one of the flags I have already positioned. The total number of different choices I can make is then
$$r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+m-1) = \frac{(r+m-1)!}{(r-1)!}$$

So if I'm right, then your argument must be wrong. But it is impossible to see what your mistake is when you don't present the *reasoning* we're asked to find mistakes in, but only its bare (and wrong) *conclusion*.

Comment: It seems you are right. My reasoning was: I have $mr$ position for the $m$ flags, some of this position will be empty, I have to choose $m$ of those positions that are not-empty. And the result is $\binom{mr}{m}$, where is the mistake?

Comment: Two problems with that. First, knowing which positions are non-empty will not tell you which flags go where. Second, the empty positions are not visible in the final result -- for example, you don't want to count "Spain at the bottom of pole 1, the rest of pole 1 empty" as different from "Spain at the top of pole 1, the rest of pole 1 empty".

Comment: Why do you have $mr$ positions?

Comment: ok you're right, I was wrong

Comment: A very good way to explain, particularly the choice of *French* names.